# Test static method with powermock and java 7

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I'm currently working on implementation unit test for my class, but when i'm running test i'm catching this exception:

```
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:55)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.<init>(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:38)
    at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:58)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:91)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:222)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:158)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.chunkClass(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:181)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:96)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:89)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:45)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader @3234e239 cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:238)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:238)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineClass0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Unsafe.java:1192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:400)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.generateConstructor(ReflectionFactory.java:514)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:427)
    at jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:103)
    ... 32 more
```

**Class:**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ZteProcessor implements OurProcessor {

    private final static String VENDOR = "ZTE";

    private String jsonString;
    private Map<String, String> metricsGU;
    private Map<String, String> metricsUMTS;
    private Map<String, String> metricsLTE;

    @Override
    public List<TimingAdvance> getTA() throws ParseException, NotFoundPatternOrMetricsException {
        TimeAdvanceDataStore data = new TimeAdvanceDataStore();
        if (jsonString.contains("String")) {
            return data.allDataToTimingAdvance(VENDOR, ProcessorUtil.getAllData(jsonString), metricsGU, 2);
        } else if (jsonString.contains("String-2")) {
            return data.allDataToTimingAdvance(VENDOR, ProcessorUtil.getAllData(jsonString), metricsUMTS, 3);
        } else if (jsonString.contains("String-3")) {
            return data.allDataToTimingAdvance(VENDOR, ProcessorUtil.getAllData(jsonString), metricsLTE, 4);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundPatternOrMetricsException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ProcessorUtil.class)
public class ZteProcessorTest {
    @Mock
    private TimeAdvanceDataStore data;

    private Map<String, String> metricsGU = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> metricsUMTS = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> metricsLTE = new HashMap<>();

    @Test
    public void getTATest() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProcessorUtil.class);
        TimingAdvance timingAdvance = new TimingAdvance();
        AllDataFromJSONFile fromJSONFile = new AllDataFromJSONFile();
        OurProcessor processor = new ZteProcessor("MSTAMeasurement", metricsGU, metricsUMTS, metricsLTE);
        List<TimingAdvance> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(timingAdvance);
        when(ProcessorUtil.getAllData("String")).thenReturn(fromJSONFile);
        when(data.allDataToTimingAdvance("ZTE", fromJSONFile, metricsGU, 2)).thenReturn(list);
        assertEquals(processor.getTA(), list);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml dependency:**

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I'm using Java 7 and JUint4. What's wrong?

Comment: 1) Is there more to the stack trace?  That exception is probably followed by a "caused by" exception which will eventually give you the underlying problem.  2) if the exception is from PowerMock where is ProcessorUtil class you're trying to mock with it? 3) Don't make ProcessorUtil static, pass it in as a dependency and then you can mock normally.

Comment: I'm added more the stack trace. ProcessorUtils is not my class, and I have to use it.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to mock `ProcessorUtils`? If you want to test your `ZteProcessor` class shouldn't you try instead to provide a matching `jsonString` for your purpose. Also what is up with `TimeAdvanceDataStore`? As it is not a dependency you can't mock it in the way you are trying to do it. There should also be no need to mock it as it is part of your implementation.

Comment: According to the stacktrace you are not using Java 7, but Java 9 or higher.